# dataframe logical_and works fine with equals and don't work with not equals

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, logical-and

Please help me understand why the "*not equal*" condition doesn't work properly.

```
>>>d = {'a' : [1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4],
>>>     'b' : [4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2]}
>>>df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    a   b
0   1   4
1   2   3
2   3   2
3   3   1
4   1   2
5   4   2
```

We get the correct result if I use the equal condition with `logical_and`:

```
>>>df[np.logical_and(df['a']==3, df['b']==2)]
    a   b
2   3   2
```

But if we change the condition to not equal it stops working correctly:

```
>>>df[np.logical_and(df['a']!=3, df['b']!=2)]
    a   b
0   1   4
1   2   3
```

This works like the condition OR instead of AND.

But it works fine again if we use `~` before `np.logical_and`

```
>>>df[~np.logical_and(df['a']==3, df['b']==2)]
    a   b
0   1   4
1   2   3
3   3   1
4   1   2
5   4   2
```

What should I know about logical conditions to avoid failure?

Comment: that's how logical negation is working... ;)

Comment: This is working fine. You just need to brush propositional logic, the [basic logical connectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Common_logical_connectives) negation, conjunction, disjunction, and their "algebraic" proprties...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should understand [***De Morgan's Laws***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

> ```
> not (A or B) == (not A) and (not B)
> ```
>
> ```
> not (A and B) == (not A) or (not B)
> ```

This is simply [*propositional logic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus), and has nothing to do with Python itself.

We can verify it ourselves with a truth table. If we make a truth table for `A and B`, we see:

```
 |A|a|
-+-+-+
B|T|F|
-+-+-+
b|F|F|
-+-+-+
```

Here `A` denotes that `A` is true, and `a` denotes that `A` is false (same for `B`). We denote `T` for true and `F` for false. Now the opposite table is thus:

```
 |A|a|
-+-+-+
B|F|T|
-+-+-+
b|T|T|
-+-+-+
```

But if we construct a truth table for `(not A) and (not B)` we obtain:

```
 |A|a|
-+-+-+
B|F|F|
-+-+-+
b|F|T|
-+-+-+
```

So the two are *not* equivalent.

See it like this: if the condition is:

> *A must be 5 and B must be 3*.

Then the opposite is **not** *A must not be 5 and B must not be 3*. Since now a case where A is 5 and B is 2 does not satisfies our first condition, but neither does it satisfies our (false) second claim. The opposite is:

> *A must not be 5 or B must not be 3* (opposite)

Since from the moment one of the two is not 5 or 3 it is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words :).

Answer (score 3):

if you're trying to filter dataframes, you may want to try something different. Have a look at [`dataframe.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

So in your example try:

```
df.loc[(df['a'] != 3) & (df['b'] != 2)]
```

it makes things a little more readable, imo

Answer (score 3):

Yet another Pandas way to do this:

```
df.query("a != 3 or b != 4")
```

Comment: Also a very valid Pandas way. just for future people coming across this post, `df.query()` uses `df.loc` `"The result of the evaluation of this expression is first passed to DataFrame.loc"` [Documentation Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

Comment: @MattR, that's correct. But the mask will be built using `pd.eval` method which makes it bit different. Beside that it might be much more pleasant for those who came from the SQL world, like myself. ;-)